# Ruby Mechanize, Nokogiri and Net::HTTP

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize, eventmachine, net-http

I am using Net::HTTP for HTTP requests and getting a response back:

```
uri = URI("http://www.example.com")
http = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, proxy_host, proxy_port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object
body = response.body
```

If I have to use the Nokogiri gem in order to parse this HTML response I will do:

```
nokogiri_obj = Nokogiri::HTML(body)
```

But if I want to use Mechanize gem I need to do this:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
mechanize_obj = agent.get("http://www.example.com")
```

Is it possible for me to use Net::Http for getting the HTML response and then use the Mechanize gem to convert it into a Mechanize object instead of using  `agent.get()`?

---

EDIT:

The reason for getting around the `agent.get()` method is because I am trying to use `EventMachine::Iterator` to make concurrent `EM-HTTP` requests.

```
EventMachine.run do
  EM::Iterator.new(urls, 3).each do |url,iter|
    puts "giving   #{url}   to httprequest now"
    http = EM::HttpRequest.new(url).get
    http.callback { |resp|
      uri = resp.send(:URI, url)
      puts "inside callback of #{url}"
      body = resp.response
      page = agent.parse(uri, resp, body)
    }
    iter.next
  end
end
```

But its not working. I am getting an error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mechanize-2.5.1/lib/mechanize.rb:1165:in`parse': undefined method `[]' for #<EventMachine::HttpClient:0x0000001c18eb30> (NoMethodError)
```

when I use the `parse` method for `Net::HTTP` it works fine and I get the Mechanize object:

```
 uri = URI("http://www.example.com")
 http = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, proxy_host, proxy_port)
 request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
 response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object
 body = response.body
 agent = Mechanize.new
 page = agent.parse(uri, response, body)
```

Am I passing the wrong arguments for the `parse` method while using em-http?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? agent.get is so much simpler.

Comment: You are doing too much work. Mechanize will handle the `get` for you. Mechanize also uses Nokogiri internally for its parsing, so it's possible to request Nokogiri's parsed doc for you to do additional lookups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think using Net::HTTP would be better. Mechanize will handle redirects and cookies, plus provides ready access to Nokogiri's parsed document.

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.example.com')

# Use Nokogiri to find the content of the <h1> tag...
puts page.at('h1').content # => "Example Domains"
```

Note, setting the `user_agent` isn't necessary to reach example.com.

---

If you want to use a threaded engine to retrieve pages, take a look at [Typhoeous and Hydra](http://typhoeus.github.com/).

Comment: yes..actually I am using Mechanize the same way later in the code to scrape the required data. But I was wondering if I could combine em-http with mechanize as mentioned in the question..

Comment: I'd recommend using Typhoeus. See my additional comment in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `Mechanize` has a [`parse` method](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize.html#method-i-parse), so this could work:

```
mechanize_obj = Mechanize.parse(uri, response, body)
```

Comment: thanks @Casper..Mechanize.parse method works correctly for Net::HTTP...how can I use the same for em-http? I think I am passing the wrong arguments to the 'parse' method while using it with em-http..

Comment: @Gameboy I would post a new question for that issue. I'm not sure the response class of `em-http` is compatible with the `Net::HTTP` response, which is what `Mechanize` is expecting. You might need to monkey-patch something or convert the response to be compatible.